# Converting JSON with nested objects to CSV not working for common solution

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I tried using [this](https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2) common solution I have found all over Stack Overflow and the internet to convert my JSON into a CSV using Javascript, but I am not getting the correct results. No othe solutions have worked so far because they don't handle nested objects.

I think my issue is that my JSON has arrays of nested objects, but I have been unable to find any solutions.

Here is a sample of my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Course": "101",
    "Student": "101",
    "quizzes": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "name__c": "Quiz 1",
        "grade__c": 100,
        "questions": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "question__c": "Question 1",
            "answer__c": "Answer 1"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "question__c": "Question 2",
            "answer__c": "Answer 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "name__c": "Quiz 2",
        "grade__c": 100,
        "questions": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "question__c": "Question 1",
            "answer__c": "Answer 1"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "question__c": "Question 2",
            "answer__c": "Answer 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is the solution I have attempted:

```
var jsonString = '[{"Id":"1","Course":"101","Student":"101","quizzes":[{"Id":"1","name__c":"Quiz 1","grade__c":100,"questions":[{"Id":"1","question__c":"Question 1","answer__c":"Answer 1"},{"Id":"2","question__c":"Question 2","answer__c":"Answer 2"}]},{"Id":"2","name__c":"Quiz 2","grade__c":100,"questions":[{"Id":"1","question__c":"Question 1","answer__c":"Answer 1"},{"Id":"2","question__c":"Question 2","answer__c":"Answer 2"}]}]}]';
var array = typeof jsonString != 'object' ? JSON.parse(jsonString) : jsonString;
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var line = '';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
        if (line != '') {
            line += ',';
        }
        line += array[i][index];
    }
    str += line + '\r\n';
}
console.log(str);
```

However, my console is printing out:

```
1,101,101,[object Object],[object Object]
```

When it should be printing out:

```
"Id","Course","Student","quizzes__Id","quizzes__name__c","quizzes__grade__c","quizzes__questions__Id","quizzes__questions__question__c","quizzes__questions__answer__c"
"1","101","101","1","Quiz 1","100","1","Question 1","Answer 1"
"","","","","","","2","Question 2","Answer 2"
"","","","2","Quiz 2","100","1","Question 1","Answer 1"
"","","","","","","2","Question 2","Answer 2"
```

I used the same JSON and used [this online converter](https://json-csv.com) and it prints the results that I need.

Is there an extra step I'm missing to handle the nested objects?

Comment: You're not expanding the nested objects, that's why you get `[object Object]`.

Comment: You need nested loops for the nested `quizzes` and `questions` arrays.

Comment: Okay, so if I extract this out to a method instead, I'll have to check if the the line is of type object, and if it is (it will be for quizzes and questions), I'll have to recursively call the method for those objects?

Comment: Also, that still doesn't explain why the keys are not being produced as the headers..

Comment: There's nothing in your code that creates the header line.

Answer (score 0):

This will be iterate over all Student courses and over quizzes and over question.
Add your preferable columns manually:

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Course": "101",
    "Student": "101",
    "quizzes": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "name__c": "Quiz 1",
        "grade__c": 100,
        "questions": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "question__c": "Question 1",
            "answer__c": "Answer 1"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "question__c": "Question 2",
            "answer__c": "Answer 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "name__c": "Quiz 2",
        "grade__c": 100,
        "questions": [
          {
            "Id": "1",
            "question__c": "Question 1",
            "answer__c": "Answer 1"
          },
          {
            "Id": "2",
            "question__c": "Question 2",
            "answer__c": "Answer 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const columnNames = ['courseId', 'studentId', 'quizId', 'questionId']
const mapToCsvRow = (items = []) => {
  return items.map((x) => `"${x}"`).join(', ')
}
const csvOutputRows = [
  mapToCsvRow(columnNames) // write column header
]

jsonData.forEach((courseData) => {
  courseData.quizzes.forEach((quizData) => {
    quizData.questions.forEach((question) => {
      csvOutputRows.push(mapToCsvRow([
        courseData.Course,
        courseData.Student,
        quizData.Id,
        question.Id,
      ]))
    })
  })
})

const csv = csvOutputRows.join("\n")
```